# how do i make a hash run a function

Tags: javascript, function, hash

i am new to javascript and  i do not know how to do a hash but here is my code the code trigers curency to change on my website currently only byt clicking on a flag but i would like to use a hash like http://hostchick.co.uk/#ca to change the princing to canadian

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.location.hash = "#ca"
{
    function changeText(1);
    function changeText(2)
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function changeText(idElement){
if(idElement==1){
document.getElementById('element'+1).innerHTML ='&pound;1.99';
} else if(idElement==2){
document.getElementById('element'+2).innerHTML ='&pound;2.99';
}
if(idElement==3){
document.getElementById('element'+1).innerHTML ='$3.15';
} else if(idElement==4){
document.getElementById('element'+2).innerHTML ='$4.73';
}
if(idElement==33){
document.getElementById('element'+1).innerHTML ='$3.16';
} else if(idElement==44){
document.getElementById('element'+2).innerHTML ='$4.75';
}
if(idElement==333){
document.getElementById('element'+1).innerHTML ='&yen;10.01';
} else if(idElement==444){
document.getElementById('element'+2).innerHTML ='&yen;29.94';
}
}
</script>
            <li><a href="#" onClick="javascript:changeText(1);javascript:changeText(2)">
test
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash = "#ca"
{
    function changeText(1);
    function changeText(2)
}
```

is syntactically invalid JavaScript, so the assignment to `location.hash` never happens.

I'm not quote clear on what you're trying to do, but maybe

```
    function changeText(1);
    function changeText(2)
```

should be

```
    changeText(1);
    changeText(2);
```

Changing the hash does not cause the page to reload, so the server isn't involved.  You can always use JavaScript to examine the hash and behave differently based on it.

Comment: ok my website www.hostchick.co.uk is base out of united kingdom but i am the part owner and i am canadian well i want to use a hash that will lunch a javascript that i have made wich will automactic change the curency and the title problem i have is i do not know how to set up the hash to c the script please go to my website http://hostchick.co.uk/ and click on 1 of the flags top left i would like to be able so when user come to the site if they #ca it will tell the javascript to show canadian pricing but as it is right now they must manualy change it